# How can I control when my gmock is verified?

Tags: c++, qt, googlemock, qtestlib

Using 'another test framework' (Qt), I want to control when the google mocks are verified:

```
void MyQtTest::test_ThisAndThat() {
     MyMock mock;
     EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(1));

     system_under_test.bar();

     //VERIFY_EXPECTATIONS(mock)
 }
```

But I don't find anything about that in the [Cookbook](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook).

Comment: Tried [this](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Verifying_and_Resetting_a_Mock)? Or did I misunderstood what are you trying to do?

Comment: @BЈовић: you understood correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what i normally do in similar situations:

```
void MyQtTest::test_ThisAndThat()
{
    MyMock mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(1));
    system_under_test.bar();

    Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(&mock);
}
```

Reference:
https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cheat_sheet.md#verifying-and-resetting-a-mock

*edit: fixed broken link*

*2nd edit: fixed broken link again*